# Mysql FIFO consumption

Tags: mysql, sql, fifo, laravel-5.8

I have 2 tables
**article_receive** , which records the the receiving via following columns;

```
item   | title     |trans_id |qty|price|current_items | current_value
ADN231 | 12" Valve |jvn2333  |24 | 175 | 24           | 4200
ADN231 | 12" Valve |jvn2388  |12 | 185 | 36           | 6420
```

Current Items is always total of all items

Current Value is value of all transaction combined (4200 + 2220)

For Issuance , i have **article_issue** with following columns;

```
item   | title     | trans_id | qty 
ADN231 | 12" Valve | ISU2333  | 6
ADN231 | 12" Valve | ISU2401  | 24
```

My requirement is , that i want to create a consumption report, which basically calculates the exact amount of items on every issuance using FIFO method.

2nd row in article_issue has items from 2 transactions and has 2 different prices. How to calculate it in **MYSQL 8.0.15 Community Version**.

Currently, i am using this SQL Statement;

```
SELECT 
article_receives.id as RCVID, article_receives.item_id, article_receives.item_title, article_receives.quantity as rcv_qty,article_receives.transaction_id, article_receives.price as rate,
article_issues.id as ISUID,article_issues.quantity as isu_qty, article_issues.quantity * article_receives.price as value
FROM article_receives
LEFT JOIN article_issues ON article_receives.item_id = article_issues.item_id
ORDER BY article_receives.item_id
/** Some Column names are changed */
```

This gives me data in following state;
[image]
Please help me out in creating a proper consumption report in mysql.
On side note, This is an app developed in laravel 5.8 , so eloquent is also available.
Thanks

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: MysqlCommunity 8.0.15

Comment: This https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154592/calculate-quantity-based-on-first-in-first-out-fifo may be useful not mysql 8 does now have window functions.

Comment: ok. let me check it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [P.Salmon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon) provided link [FIFO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154592/calculate-quantity-based-on-first-in-first-out-fifo) i was able to solve the problem.

MySql Query is :

```
WITH 
  running_purchase AS
  ( SELECT transaction_id, created_at, quantity, item_id, price,
           SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id
                               ORDER BY created_at, transaction_id
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                        AND CURRENT ROW)
             AS running_total
    FROM article_receives
  ),
  running_stock AS
  ( SELECT demand_id, created_at, quantity, item_id, 
           SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id
                               ORDER BY created_at, demand_id
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                        AND CURRENT ROW)
             AS running_total
    FROM article_issues
  )
SELECT 
    s.demand_id, p.transaction_id,p.created_at as purchase_date, p.item_id, p.price, s.created_at as issue_date,
    LEAST(p.running_total, s.running_total) 
    - GREATEST(s.running_total - s.quantity, p.running_total - p.quantity)
        AS quantity
FROM running_purchase AS p
  JOIN running_stock AS s
    ON  p.item_id = s.item_id
    AND s.running_total - s.quantity < p.running_total  
    AND p.running_total - p.quantity < s.running_total 
WHERE s.created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-01' AND DATE_ADD('2019-06-30', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY
    p.item_id, p.created_at, p.transaction_id ;
```